# Setting TINYINT value fails but MySQL Error prints nothing

Tags: php, mysql, html

Checking previous questions on the use of TINYINT values, i realize am facing a unique case hence my question. Am trying insert values into a table 'faculty' with TINYINT field using checkbox and seperate values into 'admin' table at the same time. The insert works for 'admin' table but doesn't for 'faculty' and MySQL Error prints nothing.[image: MySQL Error prints nothing]

PHP script ---

```
<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $staff_id = $_POST["staff_id"];
    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $preschool = isset($_POST["preschool"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year1 = isset($_POST["year1"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year2 = isset($_POST["year2"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year3 = isset($_POST["year3"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year4 = isset($_POST["year4"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year5 = isset($_POST["year5"]) ? 1 : 0;
    $year6 = isset($_POST["year6"]) ? 1 : 0;

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $role = "Teacher";

    $sql  = "insert into faculty (staff_id, firstname, lastname, preschool, year1, year2, year3, year4, year5, year6)";
    $sql .= " values ({$staff_id}, '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', {$preschool}, {$year1}, {$year2}, {$year3}, {$year4}, {$year5}, {$year6})";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    $sql2  = "insert into admin (staff_id, first_name, last_name, role, username, password)";
    $sql2 .= " values ({$staff_id}, '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$role}', '{$username}', '{$password}')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

    //if (!$result) {
        //echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        //exit;
    //}

    if ($result && $result2) {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "New faculty added successfully.";
        redirect_to("faculty.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Operation failed.";
        redirect_to("new_faculty.php");
    }
}
?>
```

HTML ---

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>Preschool </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="preschool">
    <label>Year 1 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year1">
    <label>Year 2 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year2">
    <label>Year 3 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year3">
    <label>Year 4 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year4">
    <label>Year 5 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year5">
    <label>Year 6 </label> &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="year6">
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are only checking for error messages **after** both queries are executed. Since the 2nd query is successful, it will void/overwrite any error message created by the 1st query. You need to check for the error message of the 1st query, after executing the 1st query, but **before** executing the 2nd query.

Comment: On a side note - it is bad practice/redundancy to put the `firstname, lastname` in both tables. Now when a name is changed, you have to update **both** tables. Just do it in the `admin` table and reference it when getting your `faculty` table.

Comment: When posting the last comment, noticed a possible reason for your insert to fail for the `faculty` table. You have the columns `first_name, last_name` in the `admin` table, but `firstname, lastname` in the `faculty` table. Is it possible that they should be `first_name, last_name` to match the `admin` table column names, as well as your php var naming structure - `$first_name`/`$last_name` with the underscore - `_`?

Comment: @Sean since am setting the form value name first_name/last_name to the variables $first_name/$last_name, using them in the table shouldn't be a problem as long as the right table column name is used in the sql statement. I will try to check for the error for the first statement as advised.

Comment: That is what I am asking. Are you using the right table column names in `insert into faculty (staff_id, firstname, lastname, ...` as the other is `insert into admin (staff_id, first_name, last_name, ...`. Typically most column names are the same, so are you sure `faculty` is without the `_`?

Comment: @Sean Yes am using the right column name. No luck checking for error from the first sql statement. Same response from mysql error ....

Comment: So have you tried `$sql  = "insert into faculty ...[rest of your query]... "; $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));`? So that if echo's the error right away if the insert query fails.

Comment: @Sean yes i have, no luck using die(mysqli_error($connection)); either.

Comment: @Sean I have been able to get the code working by simply editing isset($_POST['name']) to isset($_POST["name"])